# Custom ListView view = getChildAt(0) throw NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-listview, nullpointerexception

1. I write a custom `ListView`, named `MyListView`. In this custom class, I have a method like below:

   ```
   public int getComputedScrollY() {

       int pos, nScrollY, nItemY = 0;
       View view = null;

       // To get the first visible item position
       pos = getFirstVisiblePosition();

       // get the item view whose position is 0
       ***view = getChildAt(0);***

       if (view != null) {
           nItemY = view.getTop();
       }

       int totalOffset = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++) {
           totalOffset += mItemsHeight.get(i);
       }
       nScrollY = totalOffset - nItemY;
       return nScrollY;
   }
   ```
2. `MyListView` is used in an activity,the first time I initialize it,everything is ok.
3. But after I use the application for a long time, the activity who has `MyListView`, stay in the stopped state (after its `onStop()` is called) for a long time. Then I jump back to the activity, the codes above, the line `view = getChildAt(0)` will throw a `NullPointerException`. This is the first situation.
4. Another situation, when I use other activity,and throw any exception.The application will jump back to the activity who has MyListView automatically. Then the codes above,the same line,`view = getChildAt(0)` will throw a `NullPointerException`, too.

I don't know why.

Comment: Please paste the stacktrace

Comment: Yes please show your logcat. Without it, it's a guessing game.

Answer (score 0):

Did you scroll your listview up?

When you scrolled your Listview up and made your activity stop, maybe it is killed by the system when memory is needed elsewhere?

Comment: No,i didin't scroll it.This is a ListView that can be refreshed.The first view is a header,and it is hiden.I don't know why the method getChildAt(0) returns null.I noticed that maybe it is the matter of memory.But I don't know how to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Use getFirstVisiblePosition() instead of 0